# Need to create onChange/onSelect with javascript for dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not able to figure out how create on change/onselect function in javascript would appreciate if you could help me.

```
<div class="subdivision half">
    <select id="cabin" name "cabin" required tabindex="4">
             <option value="executive">Executive</option>
             <option value="sport">Sport</option>
             <option value="suv">SUV</option>
             <option value="standard">Standard</option>**strong text**
        </select>
     </div>
<div class="subdivision half">
     <select id="car" name="car" required tabindex="5">
         <option value="mercedes-benz s400" class="executive">Mercedes Benz S400</option>
         <option value="mercedes-benz s500" class="executive">Mercedes Benz S500</option>
         <option value="bentleyflyingspur" class="executive">Bentley Flying Spur</option>
         <option value="ferrari458" class="sport">Ferrari Italia 458</option>
         <option value="ferrari488" class="sport">Ferrari Italia 488</option>
         <option value="lambohuracain" class="sport">Lamborghini Huracain</option>
         <option value="lamboaventador" class="sport">Lamborghini Aventador</option>
      </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: I believe i didn't explain it properly, i need to change the car list when i select cabin type.

ex. if i select executive only Mercedes Benz S400,Mercedes Benz S500 and entley Flying Spur should display in other dropdown 

the same story with other cabin

Comment: for that you need to have a list of cars for each cabin type selection. You haven't shared that detail yet.

Comment: Could please show me in term of only two cabin types: Executive and Sport? the rest i will try to figure out :D appreciate

Comment: Check my fiddle again https://jsfiddle.net/zhvzt6kb/4/

Comment: i did but the same story in car category all cars are visible :'(

Comment: It is not happening for me, only the selected cabin-type cars are visible

Comment: for its not working when i go through your link :'( second day its killing me

Comment: Can you share a new fiddle where this is not working?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zhvzt6kb/4/  here it is

Comment: as you can see the  ALL CARS are there  :'(  may be i don't understand smh but it just doesn't work for me

Comment: Check this fiddle now https://jsfiddle.net/zhvzt6kb/10/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

#### Javascript

```js
function registerEvent(){
  document.getElementById("cabin").onchange = change;
  document.getElementById("car").onchange = change;
}

function change(){
  console.log("Element: ", this);
}

registerEvent();
```

```html
<div class="subdivision half">
  <select id="cabin" name "cabin" required tabindex="4">
    <option value="executive">Executive</option>
    <option value="sport">Sport</option>
    <option value="suv">SUV</option>
    <option value="standard">Standard</option>**strong text**
  </select>
</div>
<div class="subdivision half">
  <select id="car" name="car" required tabindex="5">
    <option value="mercedes-benz s400" class="executive">Mercedes Benz S400</option>
    <option value="mercedes-benz s500" class="executive">Mercedes Benz S500</option>
    <option value="bentleyflyingspur" class="executive">Bentley Flying Spur</option>
    <option value="ferrari458" class="sport">Ferrari Italia 458</option>
    <option value="ferrari488" class="sport">Ferrari Italia 488</option>
    <option value="lambohuracain" class="sport">Lamborghini Huracain</option>
    <option value="lamboaventador" class="sport">Lamborghini Aventador</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

#### jQuery - With dependent select

```js
function registerEvents() {
  $("#cabin").on("change", function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this, "option:selected").val();
    console.log(selectedValue);

    $("#car option").hide();
    $("#car option").first().show();

    // show available options
    if(selectedValue.length>0)
      $("#car ." + selectedValue.toLowerCase()).show();
    else
      $("#car option").show();
  });

  $("#car").on("change", function() {
    console.log($(this));
  })
}

registerEvents();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subdivision half">
  <select id="cabin" name "cabin" required tabindex="4">
    <option value="">Selected Type</option>
    <option value="executive">Executive</option>
    <option value="sport">Sport</option>
    <option value="suv">SUV</option>
    <option value="standard">Standard</option>**strong text**
  </select>
</div>
<div class="subdivision half">
  <select id="car" name="car" required tabindex="5">
    <option value="">Selected Car</option>
    <option value="mercedes-benz s400" class="executive">Mercedes Benz S400</option>
    <option value="mercedes-benz s500" class="executive">Mercedes Benz S500</option>
    <option value="bentleyflyingspur" class="executive">Bentley Flying Spur</option>
    <option value="ferrari458" class="sport">Ferrari Italia 458</option>
    <option value="ferrari488" class="sport">Ferrari Italia 488</option>
    <option value="lambohuracain" class="sport">Lamborghini Huracain</option>
    <option value="lamboaventador" class="sport">Lamborghini Aventador</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I believe i didn't explain it properly, i need to change the car list when i select cabin type. ex. if i select executive only Mercedes Benz S400,Mercedes Benz S500 and entley Flying Spur should display in other dropdown the same story with other cabin

should i add anything to html as well in order to run it properly?

Comment: In that case you will have to recreate dropdown with new data. I'll update my answer to depict that

Comment: Have updated my answer. Kindly check jQuery section.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhvzt6kb/1/) since you have tagged as jquery as well. This is how you capture an onchange event

```
$( "#cabin" ).change( function(){

    alert( $( this ).val() );

} );
```

Check this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhvzt6kb/10/) for your updated requirement

```
$( "#cabin" ).change( function(){

  var selectionClassValue = $( "#cabin" ).val();
  $( "#car" ).val( "" );
  $( "#car" ).find( "option" ).hide();
  $( "#car" ).find( "option" ).removeClass( "visible" );
  $( "#car" ).find( "option." + selectionClassValue ).show();
  $( "#car" ).find( "option." + selectionClassValue ).addClass( "visible" );
  $( "#car option.visible" ).first().prop('selected', true);

} );
```